# Recover data from RAID1 array (My Book Live Duo)

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, raid, data-loss

I have a WD My Book Live Duo device which I used as a network drive with a RAID1 configuration. The device, which was working flawlessly for almost 2 years suddenly stopped working, that is; it was not communicating through the network anymore. Therefore, I'm trying to recover my data. In order to do that I removed the 2 hard drives inside (2 TB each) and connected them to a PC running Ubuntu system, the problem is that I know very little about RAID1 systems and have no experience doing administrator work with such partitions / arrays. I have been trying to recover the data using information I have found on the Internet but haven't been able to access my data just yet. I'm hoping that somebody can give me a hand with this.

**sudo fdisk -l**

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes 255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System /dev/sda1               1  3907029167  1953514583+  ee  GPT Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes 255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System /dev/sdb1               1  3907029167  1953514583+  ee  GPT Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Disk /dev/sdc: 8012 MB, 8012390400 bytes 255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 974 cylinders, total 15649200 sectors Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes Disk identifier: 0x0007cb70

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System /dev/sdc1   *        2048     9420799     4709376   83  Linux /dev/sdc2         9422846    15648767     3112961    5  Extended /dev/sdc5         9422848    15648767     3112960   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/md3: 1995.8 GB, 1995774484480 bytes 2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 487249630 cylinders, total 3897997040 sectors Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md3 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

**cat /proc/mdstat**

```
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] md3 : active raid1 sda4[0]
      1948998520 blocks super 1.0 [2/1] [U_] md2 : inactive sda3[0](S)
      500724 blocks super 1.0
```

**sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sda4**

```
/dev/sda4:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.0
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 6328fe8f:fe1171d8:081e7373:f0f4c10c
           Name : MyBookLiveDuo:3   Creation Time : Wed Jul 25 23:18:29 2012
     Raid Level : raid1    Raid Devices : 2
 Avail Dev Size : 3897997040 (1858.71 GiB 1995.77 GB)
     Array Size : 1948998520 (1858.71 GiB 1995.77 GB)    Super Offset : 3897997296 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 4fc654bb:b038b5f5:95b07dfb:cb72a9fd
    Update Time : Fri Oct 17 14:51:18 2014
       Checksum : e6c639fd - correct
         Events : 2776221
   Device Role : Active device 0    Array State : A. ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
```

**sudo mount /dev/md3 /mnt/raid**

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md3,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

**sudo mdadm --examine --scan**

```
ARRAY /dev/md/2 metadata=1.0 UUID=ff212100:102164c7:d017c1b8:c595e2ba name=MyBookLiveDuo:2    
     spares=1 

ARRAY /dev/md/3 metadata=1.0 UUID=6328fe8f:fe1171d8:081e7373:f0f4c10c name=MyBookLiveDuo:3
```

EDIT:

**sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda**

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.8

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sda: 3907029168 sectors, 1.8 TiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 79317853-5A49-4E58-83F9-CB068223B1D5
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 3907029134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 30829 sectors (15.1 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1         1032192         5031935   1.9 GiB     FD00  primary
   2         5031936         9031679   1.9 GiB     FD00  primary
   3           30720         1032191   489.0 MiB   FD00  primary
   4         9031680      3907028991   1.8 TiB     FD00  primary
```

**sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdb**

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.8

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sdb: 3907029168 sectors, 1.8 TiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 5F5A7F2D-1D3C-434A-9CCD-FB8AED835564
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 3907029134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 3907029101 sectors (1.8 TiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
```

EDIT2:

This is the output I get in dmesg when trying to mount /dev/md3

```
EXT4-fs (md3): bad block size 65536
```

EDIT3:

**sudo parted -l**

```
Model: ATA WDC WD20EURS-63S (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 3      15,7MB  528MB   513MB                primary  raid
 1      528MB   2576MB  2048MB  ext3         primary  raid
 2      2576MB  4624MB  2048MB  ext3         primary  raid
 4      4624MB  2000GB  1996GB  ext4         primary  raid


Model: ATA WDC WD20EURS-63S (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start  End  Size  File system  Name  Flags


Model: ATA CFast D150Q (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 8012MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  4823MB  4822MB  primary   ext4            boot
 2      4824MB  8012MB  3188MB  extended
 5      4824MB  8012MB  3188MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)


Model: Linux Software RAID Array (md)
Disk /dev/md3: 1996GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0,00B  1996GB  1996GB  ext4
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Andres

Comment: `fdisk` is for MBR partitioned disks only. For GPT partitioned disks use `gdisk`. You can [edit] your question to replace that section. Please use the “code sample“ formatting instead of “blockquote“ for pre-formatted sections. Did you use `mdadm` to manage the RAID on those drives in the first place? What's the output of `sudo blkid /dev/mda{2,3}`?

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your comments. I edited my post using your suggested format. Executing blkid /dev/mda{2,3} doesn't produce any output.

Comment: Should have been `blkid /dev/md/{2,3}` – my mistake. What about the other info I asked you about in my previous comment?

Comment: Hi David, I just added the gdisk output instead of replacing as the fdisk may add information anyway even though it doesn't support GPT partitions. Regarding your question on mdadm: I didn't create these partitions myself, these are disks taken out from a WD MyBookLiveDuo device which somehow doesn't works anymore and I'm trying to recover the data on them. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @David Forester: the blkid command still doesn't produce any output

Comment: Are the two devices in `/dev/md` still there? Because `mdadm --examine` seems to have found them. If `blkid /dev/md*` doesn't work, what does `file -s /dev/md/*` have to say? Also sdb seems to have no GPT partition for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to mount the raid 1 array and recover my data. This is what I used:

```
sudo fuseext2 -o ro -o sync_read -o allow_other /dev/sda4 /mnt/raid
```

For more information refer to this excellent blog article:

[Recovering data from a WD Mybook Live 2TB / 3TB (or similar)][1]http://john-hunt.com/2013/04/25/recovering-data-from-a-wd-mybook-live-2tb-3tbor-similar/

Comment: The "allow other" switch is a necessary improvement over John Hunt's excellent article. I needed both threads to get it working. It is a troubling commentary that WD does not have much of anything on their web site on the topic. It is their drive, they do support Raid 1, yet they do not give a recovery tool. Why?